# POST request returning text/html and not JSON, how do I get the JSON in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, post, http-post

For work, we verify voter registration through state websites. A recent update broke our verification.

They now require an XSFR token/cookie. I've been able to retrieve the cookie with the code below and submit it in a POST request. The server responds with code 200. If you comment out the cookie/XSFR you will see it responds with 403.

I'm using the Request Module. The server responds with an HTML/Text file and not the JSON file like it does in a browser. What am I doing wrong? I've included some dummy info if the info is bad info the server still responds with a JSON file. Any help would be appriciated!

I've removed the links we use for voter verification and replaced them with Google.com per issue fixed.

```
//using request module    npm install request --save

var request = require('request');
var jar = request.jar();
var request = request.defaults({
jar: jar,
});
var jar = request.jar();

// get cookie for XSRF token

request.get({
    url: 'https://www.google.com',
    method: 'get',
    jar: jar
}, () => {
    cookies = jar.getCookies('https://www.google.com');
    //output cookie
    console.log(cookies);
    var cookieToString = cookies.toString()
    //slice token for cookie response
    var xsrfCookie = cookieToString.slice(0, 47)
    //slice token for token response
    var slicedCookie = cookieToString.slice(11, 47)

    //send POST with xsrf token & cookie

    var request = require('request');
    var options = {

        uri: 'https://www.google.com',
        headers: {
            //custom HTTP headers for response
            Host: 'votesearch.google.com',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            Referer: 'https://www.google.com',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': slicedCookie,
            //'Content-Length': '118', leave commented out or server response hangs - not sure why
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            Cookie: xsrfCookie,
            Pragma: 'no-cache',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            city: 'sometown',
            dob: '01-01-1950',
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            street: '1234 street',
            zip: '12345'
        }
    }
    //server responsds with content type 'text/html' not JSON like in browser
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body.id) // Print the shortened url - not working.
            console.log(response.headers); // can I get JSON from this?
            console.log(response.statusCode)


        } else {
            console.log('response code ' + response.statusCode);
            console.log('error ' + error)
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a request using the `request` module, in order to include a JSON encoded request body in a request, the `body` option should be set to a JSON serializable object, and the `json` field should be set to `true`.

Setting the `json` field to `true` will also ensure that the response will be parsed as JSON and made available in the `body` field of the response.

In the second request in ur code snippet, the `json` field is set to an object, which is not a valid value.

Comment: You're the man, I just want you to know that I got it fixed and working.  Thanks!